# Submit button doesn't work on enter in IE aspp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:Button ID="newbutton" runat="server" Text="Click" onsubmit="button_click" OnClick="button_click"  />
```

I have this button in update panel and i want it to work on enter not only onclick it works in google chrome , but not in ie what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the panel set the default button to the id of the button

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" id="examplePanel" DefaultButton="newbutton">
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the default button for update panel with the Id of this button

Sample:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTest" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pTest" DefaultButton="newbutton">
                <asp:Button ID="newbutton" runat="server" Text="Click" onsubmit="button_click" OnClick="button_click"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

`ASP:Button` cannot work with `enter` because it has `OnClick`. To react on enter properly you should use `ASP:Panel` with `DefaultButton` property. You need to have focus on control inside asp:Panel for example `TextBox`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="newbutton">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TxtUserLogin" runat="server" TabIndex="1" Text="login" />
            <asp:Button ID="newbutton" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="button_click"  />
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```